# Can't figure out the general formula for electric circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, diagram

I have the following setup. Note the device in the middle says P, not R, so I now how many Watts the device produces. (I'm not sure if I drew the correct symbol there)
[image]
Calculating the current resolves to a quadratic equation, which I can solve:
[image]
This gives 2 values for I, one of which will result in negative values (right?) and can be discarded.
Now, when I add another device (and then another and another), it becomes too complicated for me:
[image]
I figure there must be some general formula that I can plug into the previous one at each step.
The ultimate goal is to figure out how many devices can be added before the voltage becomes too low, considering each P and the lengths of the wires (which is what R1, R2, etc represents) Can someone figure this out?

**Update:**
As it turns out, working backwards is extremely easy, e.g. asking the question: "If I need a minimum of v Volts over the last device, what does \$V_0\$ need to be?" It's just a matter of adding voltages and currents.
Working forwards in the way I imagined is not doable, e.g. asking the question: "If \$V_0\$ = v Volts, what is the voltage over the last device?" This can be done with iteration.

Everyone keeps saying the voltage drop from the wires doesn't matter, but it does. With 25W devices, depending on the number of devices we hook up and lengths of wires (which can be hundreds of meters), we can get voltage drops from the wires that are over 10% of the voltage drops from the devices. 2 or 3 Volts per wire is significant in our situation.
Thnx for your help, everyone!

Comment: Both solutions of your quadratic are positive.  The value you take the square root of is less than V0, so even if you select the minus sign the numerator of the right hand side is positive.

Comment: Comment on some things that are said in the answers: This is not about simple light bulbs. We are talking about industrial sensors with a bunch of electronics inside. These are placed in buildings, bridges, dykes, etc. The total length of wire can be hundreds of meters. I was told their resistance could matter, so I put it in. This is how the problem was presented to me. I'm a programmer, not an electrical engineer, so I used the wrong wordings here and there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually a classic problem in electrical installations, i.e. knowing the power consumption of several devices plugged to an electrical line, what is the voltage drop in the farther device? It is normally solved using an approximation, so it doesn't give the exact value, but rather close (and pessimistic one).

I'll drawn the problem in a different way, unipolar diagram:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5jRRX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

(R1+R2) represent the resistance of the two wires (L and N) in the first section, P1 is the power drawn by the first device, etc.

Delta_V is the voltage drop in the last device.

The approximation is that voltage drop will be small and therefore the current at each device can be approximated by:  $$ i_k=P_k/V$$ where \$V\$ is the nominal voltage (your \$V_0\$). In fact the voltage will be a little smaller than this, and therefore the real current too. (Edit: this deserves an explanation: a 100 W bulb if fed by less voltage than nominal, will draw less current than nominal. If it was a "clever" bulb, it would get more current so that it keeps the 100 W, but it is not the case in normal passive devices).

Then the voltage drop at the end of the line is given by:
$$\Delta V=(R_1+R_2)·(i_1+i_2+i_3)+(R_3+R_4)·(i_2+i_3)+(R_5+R_6)·i_3$$

This can be generalized for as many devices as you want. The idea is that the currents of all the devices will go through the first section (that's why there is \$i_1+i_2+i_3\$ multiplying the first section resistance), in the second section all but the first device, etc.

The value found by this formula is a worst case. The real drop will be smaller.

If you want to go exact, then this iterative procedure could be followed:

1. Calculate the voltage drops at every node and not only the last (it is easy to figure how)
2. Estimate again the currents at each device using the information provided by the voltage drops found in the previous step.
3. Go again to step 1 and repeat until the currents and the voltage drops converge.

Those steps can be written in matricial form and evaluated through Matlab. I don't know if Mathematica or Maple would also be able to find a closed form solution!

I've tried this algorithm with the following values. P1=200 W, P2=50 W and P3=100 W. Resistor values R1+R2=5 Ohms, R3+R4=5 Ohms and R5+R6=5 Ohms. The nominal voltage is 230 V. Those are the results (every column is an iteration, and every row is one node):

[image: Simulation]

You can see that after a few iterations, the voltages and currents converge, and the power drawn at each node has the desired value.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not saying I can give you an answer but i can simplify things a tad: -

To start with call the two series fixed value resistors just one resistor, R. This reduces apparent complexity with no loss of accuracy. Call the resistance of the constant power source Rp

\$I = \dfrac{V_I}{R+R_P}\$ Then introduce the power dissipated, k = \$\dfrac{V_O^2}{R_P}\$ or \$R_P = \dfrac{V_O^2}{k}\$.

Plug back in the equation and multiply top and bottom by k to get \$I = \dfrac{k\cdot V_I}{k\cdot R + V_O^2}\$

Noting that \$k = V_O \cdot I\$ and rearranging: -

\$V_O\cdot I^2\cdot R+ I\cdot V_O^2 = V_I\cdot V_O\cdot I\$ then divide thru by I to get \$V_O\cdot I\cdot R+ V_O^2 = V_I\cdot V_O\$

Re substitute for k to get: -

\$k\cdot R+ V_O^2 = V_I\cdot V_O\$ and then solve for Vo: -

\$V_O = \dfrac{V_I \pm \sqrt{V_I^2-4\cdot k\cdot R}}{2}\$

A quick sanity check for when k is zero leads to: -

\$V_O = \dfrac{V_I \pm \sqrt{V_I^2}}{2}\$ and this looks right to me (Vo = Vi).

I think this is an easier formula to move forward with (hope I got the math right!)

Next, I have a feeling that using matrices will help ala 2-port networks. It's still going to get a little crazy after a few terms though so hopefully someone may spot a trick.

I'm wondering if the formula for the golden ratio might work?

Answer (score 1):

Why are you assuming that \$P_3\$ is a resistance? All you know is that's it's consuming power. What you have here are two unknowns -- the current in the loop and the voltage across \$P_3\$. To solve this problem, you will need two equations -- a KVL equation for the loop, and a power equation for \$P_3\$. Assuming the current flows clockwise:

$$V_0 - IR_1 - V_{P3} - IR_2 = 0$$
$$P_{P3} = V_{P3}I$$

You can solve this directly using a computer algebra system like the one in a TI-89 or the [free one in Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%2010%20-%205*x%20-%2010*x%20-%20u%20%3D%200%20and%201%20%3D%20u*x), or you can use matrix methods, or you can use substitution. Substitution gives you the equation you found:

$$V_0 - IR_1 - IR_2 - \frac{P_{P3}}{I} = 0$$

There are two possible solutions since the second equation is a product of two variables. You don't get a negative solution, though. I tried several made-up numbers for \$V_0\$ and \$P_3\$ and always got positive solutions. Since the power equation is of the form \$y = \frac{1}{x}\$, I think both solutions will always be positive. (This is more obvious on the Wolfram Alpha graph result.) Physically, this means that you can obey KVL and conservation of energy with both a high voltage/low current and a low voltage/high current solution. If you pick exactly the right values of \$V_0\$, \$R_1\$, \$R_2\$, and \$P_3\$ you can get a single solution, but that's a coincidence, not a method.

You need an extra constraint to get down to one solution. I don't see a physically necessary one, although I might be missing something. One choice would be to say that \$P_3\$ must be greater than the power consumed by the resistors -- i.e., that this circuit is *efficient*. Your description of the problem suggests that there might be a minimum voltage required, which could also work.

Once you've solved the problem for a single power sink, you can move on to two. Now you can use mesh analysis, which gives four equations and four unknowns. As you've noticed, this is too complicated for a general solution. This seems like a two-port network problem, but I don't know enough two-port network theory to help you there.

You can get an approximate upper bound by looking at the ultimate current limit:

$$\sum{P_n} < \frac{V_0}{R_1 + R_2}$$

Are you sure you've given us all the information? It seems like something important is missing.

Answer (score 1):

There is some general formula that "plugs into" the previous one, but due to how your circuit is set up, it does not plug in in a "nice" way.

First of all, I don't really understand what you are trying to say with the formula for R3 that you provided. It also holds true for the other resistors in your schematic, because:

```
R = U / I
and
P = U * I or U = P / I
together
R = P / I²
```

You are also saying it "produces watts", which is a bit odd. What I think you have is something like a lightbulb, with a certain power rating in watts.
That rating doesn't mean it "produces" that many watts, it merely states how much power this device will consume.
Devices need a certain voltage to work: 24V, 12V, 230V or 120V.
The watt rating doesn't tell you this number. It is an additional information.
There should be a label on the device telling you the voltage.

Oddly enough, you are presenting a formula that calculates a current.

Here's how you get to the formula:
With only one device, you have a simple voltage divider.

```
V3 / V0 = R3 / (R1 + R2)
or
V3 = R3 / (R1 + R2) * V0
```

Keep in mind that R1 + R2 are very small, so the voltage V3 won't be that much different to V0. R1 and R2 are probably negligible.

I use the parallel operator || to keep things short:

```
a||b = a * b / (a + b)
```

Now add the second device.
The voltage divider changes, you are adding 3 additional resistors to the circuit: R4, R5 and R6.
More specifically, you add them in parallel to R3.
Basically speaking, you always add the 3 resistors in parallel to the second resistor of the previously added resistors.

This is where the next device "plugs in":

```
V3 = R3 || (R4 + R5 + R6) / (R1 + R2) * V0
```

The interesting thing is how you can calculate V6 easy now.
If you think of V3 as the supplied voltage now, the circuit of the second device behaves like the first one with respect to V3 (instead of V0)

```
V6 / V3 = R6 / (R4 + R5)
or
V6 = R6 / (R4 + R5) * V3
or, inserting the formula for V3 from above:
V6 = R6 / (R4 + R5) * R3 || (R4 + R5 + R6) / (R1 + R2) * V0
```

These formulas mix both serial and parallel circuitry nested into each other.
This makes it hard to provide a closed formula for arbitrary many devices.

To illustrate, let's take the above and see how a third device expands, the formulas:

The third device will add 3 resistors again, in parallel to R6. This changes V3 as follows:

```
V3 = R3 || (R4 + R5 + (R6 || (R7 + R8 + R9) ) / (R1 + R2) * V0
```

which in turn changes V6 to:

```
V6 = R6 / (R4 + R5) * R3 || (R4 + R5 + (R6 || (R7 + R8 + R9) ) / (R1 + R2) * V0
```

The voltage of the new device with respect to the previous one is a simple voltage divider again:

```
V9 / V6 = R9 / (R7 + R8)
or
V9 = R9 / (R7 + R8) * V6
```

I hope you see the pattern emerging that you were asking for.

**And now for something completely different: real life**

Wires have a very low resistance. Negligibly low.
The wires will not cause the voltage to drop too low on your devices.
You are probably save to assume the voltage is pretty much the same.

Your question is what limits the amount of devices you can chain together.
The answer is **the power supply**.
Every device that you add adds to the current being drawn from the supply and it can only deliver a certain amount.

The math is very easy here:
You cannot use more watts than your supply supplies.
Sum up all the watts on your devices and see if your supply can deliver that much (if it does more, no problem)
**There's no way around this.**

Comment: I understand what you have provided here, thnx for that. I know that `V=I*R` and `P=V*I` and all that. That wasn't the problem.
You give me `V3 / V0 = R3 / (R1 + R2)`
Just before that, you say: "I don't really understand what you are trying to say with the formula for R3 that you provided." and: "Oddly enough, you are presenting a formula that calculates a current." Answer: to find the R3 you are using in your formula (and thus V3). THAT is the whole problem: finding R3. But to get R3, I calculate the I first...

Comment: ...Then I got confused when I add a 2nd device, because now the current that goes through P3 is not the same current that goes through R1, because it splits up, and so the voltages are different too. I couldn't see the forest through the trees. Also see my comment underneath the question: this is not about simple light bulbs. I don't think  you can simply sum up the Watts, because there's a minimal requirement for the voltage. That's why I stated in the question: "The ultimate goal is to figure out how many devices can be added before the voltage becomes too low".

Comment: @Dennis_E: again, there's pretty much always a certain voltage that a device requires. But as I said, chaining devices up in parallel will not reduce the voltage significantly because the resistance of wires is negligible. I have the impression that you are mistaking electrical power for something you use to solve linear electrical networks, but in fact it's not. As I said: the resistors you included in the circuit have the same power relationship as you stated for R3, yet you only treat R3 in a special way by incorporating the power formula into your solution.